# "Question and Answers" equivalent when it's not a question

Tags: word-choice, nouns, phrase-requests, analogy

There is a common phrase, "Questions and Answers", also known as Q&A.

If you have a viewpoint. opinion, idea, statement, or a thought etc., what phrase would represent it and the response the best? In other words, the equivalent to "Questions and Answers" when referring to opinions, thoughts, ideas, etc., is what?

Some possible combinations I have thought of are "Viewpoints and Reactions", and "Opinions and Responses". There are probably others, but I am searching for the most proper. Also, in my opinion, "Comments and Feedback" seem too similar to "Questions and Answers".

Comment: In what context do you plan to use these words? I think some more details would help. There is *thesis-antithesis*, *argument-reply*, *proposition-objection*, and many other combinations. What are you going to describe by those words?

Comment: It's for a website I am developing for a client. There are several areas on the website and the client wants one phrase to generically handle all of the discussion possibilities. "Opinions and Responses" don't apply to someone posting an idea, nor does "Viewpoints and Reactions". Just looking for a happy medium that accurately but generically describes several types of discussion possibilities.

Comment: Okay, the only thing generic enough I can think of would be *message/reply* or *post/reply*. Or possibly *topic/reply*. Or *initiative/response*.

Comment: I hate stupid clients.

Comment: technically it is a forum; the *topic* of such area of the forum can be any of the phrases you came up with (seriously instead of "opinions, thoughts, ideas, etc" you can put *a lot* of other things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this suit your taste?

> Speculation and Debate

or

> Theory and Feedback

Comment: You're on the right track, but I am thinking theory and speculation are a bit non-factual for the purpose I need it for.

Answer (score 1):

Does it specifically need to be "X and Y"?  Because it sure sounds like "discussion" to me.

If you want the "X and Y" format, you sometimes see "point/counterpoint" (usually without the "and", though).

Comment: Yeah, "X and Y" are preferred, and yes, it is discussion, but different types of discussion. Point/counterpoint works well to describe some types of discussion, but not as a generic way to describe all, like someone presenting an idea, and others responding to the idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about Thoughts and Theories?

Answer (score -2):

***Discussion and Opinion Exchange***.